# Hide ImageView on clicks

Tags: java, android, imageview

Thanks for all suggestion and thoughts i finally achieved it by yours suggestions and it was a simple logic work to solve the problem. I want to share it if any one want to create custom Health Bar , but  it is not suitable for 100 HP because then you have to write 100 IF statements, 
Idea was to create simple custom Healthbar and decrease it by pressing button clicks. 
This link also help me a lot. 
[HealthBar](http://www.neongalahadgames.com/index.php/andengine-health-bar/)
**Code**

```
private TextView Message,result;
private Button play;
private float maxHP = 10;
private float currentHP = maxHP;
//private float percentHP =  (float) (currentHP/maxHP);
private int user_shield;
private float healthBar;
private ImageView shieldusb1,shieldusb2,shieldusb3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_one);

Initialize();

}


private void Initialize(){ 
   user_shield = R.raw.shield_blue;
   shieldusb2 = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.shield_b2);
   shieldusb1 = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.shield_b1);
   shieldusb3 = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.shield_b3);
   result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
   play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
   play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            play();
}
   });

}

public void play(){
    {         
        healthBar=0;
        currentHP = (float) (currentHP - 0.5);       

        //currentHP -= 1;
    if(currentHP <= 0) //if the player died
    {
         currentHP = 0; //set his HP to zero, (just in case)
         Message.setText("You died! :P"); //add any extra death-code here
         //update the healthBar
         result.setText ("WIN POINTS"); 
    }
    updateHealthBar();
  }

    }
 private void updateHealthBar() {   
    // percentHP =  currentHP / maxHP;
     healthBar = currentHP;


     if(healthBar<9.6){
            shieldusb1.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
     }
     {               
     if (healthBar<=9){
            shieldusb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
     if (healthBar<=8.6){
        shieldusb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
     }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `healthBar` is of **int** type, so checking against 0.9 is the same as checking against 1.

Also, in your conditions, you're first checking:

```
if (healthBar <= 1)
```

If this condition is true, you're hiding shieldusb1, and you will never reach second condition because you have used `else`. What you can do is to remove `else` in front of second condition, but as said above, your healthBar is int, so the second condition is basically the same as the first. Change healthBar to double.

Comment: Hello Melq , by removing else and using "IF"both images are hiding on a single click and not when the condition satisfy

Comment: Yes, because your variables are int, but also, if you do the math, when button is pressed, `healthBar` is 0, so both conditions are satisfied, because 0 <= 1 and 0 <= 0.9. First, change your variables to `double`, then check the calculations again, eg. in play(), if you decrement by 0.5, not 5, after button click, healthBar will be 0.95, which will satisfy first condition, but not the second (this will be satisfied after second button click).

Answer (score 1):

My guess, is you need to remove the **else if** and make it just **if** because if you execute first statement where <= 1, else if will never get executed.

```
private void updateHealthBar() {   
    percentHP = currentHP / maxHP; / calculating points 
    healthBar = percentHP;


    if(healthBar<=1){           // Hiding first Image View 
        shieldusb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
    }
    if (healthBar<=0.9){  
       shieldusb2.setVisibility(View.GONE); //  How to Hide this Image View after button click 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust these conditions

```
if(healthBar<=1)
...
else if (healthBar<=0.9)
```

Even if `healthBar<= 0.9` evaluates true, `healthBar<=1` is also true so it will always enter the first `if`

Answer (score 0):

You check if healthBar is <= 1, and after if is <= 0.9... But this case never verify, cause 0.9 is < 1, so it always choose the first option!
Change your first if for check values between 1 and 0.9, and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

It's only logical problem. Change if/else if block for if/if.

```
 if(healthBar<=1)
    shieldusb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
 if (healthBar<=0.9)
    shieldusb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: what logical problem. Tell him.